how to change the widget button's text in android
i am very new to android and tying to make a simple to-do list widget
The text on the widget button doesnt change.
The activity launchs, but once i type inside the textfield the text from the text field doesnt get stored in the button
this is my current code which is inside an onCreate fun of an activity that gets launched when clicked on said button
inside mainactivity.kt

val remoteViews: RemoteViews = RemoteViews("com.example.noteswidget", R.layout.widget)
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_Button,it.text)

inside widget.xml
<Button
        android:id="@+id/appwidget_Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="@string/appwidget_text" /> 

i am very new to android, i may have made some noob mistakes

Based on your code i don't know why your logic like that. I'll give you sample code.
activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_print"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Sample"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_click"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click it"/>

</LinearLayout>

Then in MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //first init
    private lateinit var btnClick: Button
    private lateinit var textPrint: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }

        //assign variable with value
        btnClick = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_click)
        textPrint = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_print)

        //do actions
        btnClick.setOnClickListener {
            textPrint.text = btnClick.text
        }

    }
}

In the sample above, there are several types if you used findViewById

Create name of the variable your component
Binding the variable with the xml files using findViewById
Do the actions

In that sample when button is clicked, so the textview will show the text in the button.
But, my recommendations you can learn about ViewBinding to better development. Because that is very helpful for you, and make your work more efficient. Happy to code :)
